# TortoiseSVN Unable to openan ra_local session to URL win XP

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to use svn through svnTortoise on a windows xp machine.  Its just me, just trying to do it in house.  On my laptop I installed tortoise and everything works great.  Then I came to my desktop and installed svnTortoise and tried it.  But this time I get these errors.

```
Checkout from file://F:/repos/mav_admin, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
Unable to open repository 'file://f:/repos/mav_admin'
Finished!
```

I've tried for local repositories, or the same repositories that my laptop was using... nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

Anytime I try to import or checkout on my desktop I get the above error, but not when I use my laptop.  My laptop is running Vista... (didn't want to pay to downgrade...) and my desktop computer is a 64-bit computer... but I'm running 32-bit XP.

Tortoise Info is

```
TortoiseSVN 1.6.0, Build 15855 - 32 Bit , 2009/03/21 12:36:36
Subversion 1.6.0, 
apr 1.3.3
apr-utils 1.3.4
neon 0.28.4
OpenSSL 0.9.8j 07 Jan 2009
zlib 1.2.3
```

Comment: Did you try file://F:/... or file:///F:/? (You need the three slash version)

Comment: I need three slashes?  That might be it... I'll try that.  I was under impression the /// was on unix/linux because it was file:// and then the third / was meaning the root of the filesystem.

Comment: I think you have uploaded the file and tried to commit again this file. So Please download your required file from repository(repo brows) then try to commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [unable-to-open-repository-error-on-windows-xp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507299/unable-to-open-repository-error-on-windows-xp) for a similar problem.

Possible causes:

- Are you using the same client on all computers? I think the Tortoise 1.6 may drop support for file:// access.
- Are you using a BDB or fsfs repository?
- Do you have correct file permissions to the repository?

UPDATE: From [tsvn_1.6_releasenotes.html](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/tsvn_1.6_releasenotes.html)

> TortoiseSVN 1.6 no longer supports
> access to BDB repositories via the
> file:/// url. This doesn't affect
> accessing BDB repositories over svn://
> or http:// though.
>
> If you have a BDB repository that you
> still access via the file:/// url, you
> have to convert the repository to the
> FSFS format with the svnadmin tool
> which is available in the SVN command
> line client.
>
> Please follow the instructions in the Subversion book to convert the repository.

Answer (score 22):

You need a third '/' before the drive letter:

```
file:///F:/repos/mav_admin
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. Haven't quite solved it, but I have found a simple (or stupid, whatever you like) workaround.
TortoiseSVN won't open repository created in other drives than C (where WinXP and TortoiseSVN are installed). On C, it works perfectly.
I'm a SVN newbie, so if this is a well-known bug or expected behavior, please comment.

Comment: You can try `TortoiseSVN -> Relocate` command to solve this. Just specify the new drive letter and you're done...

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Tortoise SVN was returning "Unable to open an ra_local session to URL" error on import. It was because svn was unable to find the repository. Please make sure

1. you've created the repository e.g. Project and is accessible.
2. Also, you have created correct structure
   e.g.  C:\tmp\new\branches
        C:\tmp\new\tags
        C:\tmp\new\trunk

   1. Move the contents of \Project into the trunk sub-directory (C:\tmp\new\trunk)
   2. Right click on 'new' directory and import.
      this should work.

Ref: http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to TortoiseSVN - Settings - Saved Data. Hit the clear buttons at URL  history, Log messages (Input dialog) and Log messages (Show log dialog)
Not sure you have to hit all 3 clear buttons but it solved it for me.
After that you have to retype the url of the repository location.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but found another solution...

I was using a lot of 'externals' but had been using absolute file locations. I simply changed the file path to from absolute to references and the errors went away.

Within Repco Browser, select the file and then select the "..." button next to it then select OK. TortoiseSVN automatically converts file path using references.